# How to find time difference between current date and another date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm searching a way to find the time difference between 2 dates using moment js in seconds only.
I want to compare current date with dates that I'm reading from the database.

For example:

```
//current time
var current_time= moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');      
//date from sql query
var starting_date=moment(element.start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// print the dates as they are now
console.log(current_time);
console.log(starting_date);
```

result:

```
2019-07-02 18:00:11
2019-05-03 15:59:29
```

I want to find the difference between these 2 dates in seconds only.

I try to make it work using something like this example i found:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days')
```

but it doesn't worked...

```
    var current_time= moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');      
    var starting_date=moment(element.start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      current_time.diff(starting_date, 'seconds');
```

it crashes

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: How exactly did `.diff()` not work?

Comment: "doesn't worked" - can you elaborate on this? did you get an empty console log? Did you get a diff of 0? Did nothing happen at all?

Comment: Your example of `diff` results in `1` day which is correct for that code, but you do not show how you try to adapt this to you problem case with seconds where it does not work. You need to show **your** [mcve] try of using `diff`.

Comment: @Lewis i try to say for example current_time.diff(starting_date, 'seconds');  and the result was an error "current_time.diff is not a function"

Comment: That implies current_time is not a moment object. Was it created using the code above?

Comment: Using `moment.diff` you can calculate the difference in seconds by specifying you want diff in seconds. CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVKqEG?editors=1111 You can verify the result here: https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=07&d1=02&y1=2019&m2=05&d2=03&y2=2019&h1=18&i1=00&s1=11&h2=15&i2=59&s2=29

Answer (score 0):

You can use `a.unix() - b.unix()`

`a.diff(b)` will return diff in `millisecond`, you can div for 1000 to get second.

```js
var a = moment('2019-07-02 18:00:11', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var b = moment('2019-05-03 15:59:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
second = a.unix() - b.unix();  

console.log('diff with second:' + second);


secondbymin = a.diff(b);
console.log('diff with milisecond: ' + secondbymin);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: thnks but the dates that I want to compare are not in the format like a and b in the example. if you try the same for the   values var current_time= moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');      
        and  
     var starting_date=moment(element.start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');            it doesn work

Comment: I updated answer for your format date

Comment: If you want to second by diff method, you can div / 1000

Comment: did you fix your issue @NikosKalantas?

Comment: yes after some tries it worked with this way: 
var starting_date=moment(element.start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); 
             starting_date = moment(starting_date);
             current_time = moment(current_time);
(starting_date.diff(current_time, 'seconds')

Comment: format method will return string value, why don't use unix or diff method?